# Camera 2 API issue, images always displayed in landscape mode

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, android-camera2

Images displayed by custom camera using camera 2 API are always in landscape mode, even if image is captured in portrait, how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set display oriantion like

```
 mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

also You can convert taken picture byte array into a bitmap and then rotate that bitmap and do whatever you want

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
rotatedBitmap = CameraUtils.rotateBitmap(bitmap,270);
 public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(@NonNull Bitmap bitmap, int rotation) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(rotation);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }
```